# Recommended IIS 7.5 books

Tags: iis-7.5

Can somebody recommend good reading material for administrating IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 4):

No books. but http://www.iis.net/ has pretty much all you need.

http://learn.iis.net/ in particular. A book is not needed, imho.

Comment: +1, Microsoft's online documentation for almost all of their products is superb. IIS.net, technet, msdn, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best for IIS 7 is [Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0 Resource Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735624410) 
It is still relevant for IIS 7.5, since there were few major changes in IIS 7.5 and you can definitely learn about those in IIS.net like:[IIS7 in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://blogs.iis.net/mailant/archive/2009/01/11/iis7-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the one that you should be looking at is [Professional IIS 7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470097825)